# Can't find Source files for Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

My Provider do not allow to install the Lavendel-Framework. So I do not have access to the Lavendel-Structure. But I would like to clone some functions. Especcialy the collect function.
For this I download the complete libray from https://github.com/laravel/laravel and scan the files for collect. But there is no collect. What is the secret here. Where are the Source-files. Isn't it open source?

```
$collection = collect(['taylor', 'abigail', null])->map(function ($name) {
        return strtoupper($name);
    })
    ->reject(function ($name) {
        return empty($name);
    });
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections

Comment: You are looking for https://github.com/illuminate/support package. I like your name.

Comment: yes it's hamburger: Say it with a cheese ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're searching in the wrong package my friend. The function is declared [here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.4/src/Illuminate/Support/helpers.php#L384). Notice that it's in `laravel/framework` package, not `laravel/laravel`.

To get the idea of which packages are being pulled, look at `composer.json` file. You will see something like:

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.6.4",
    "laravel/framework": "5.4.*",
    "laravel/tinker": "~1.0"
},
```